# Using IE11 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, internet-explorer-11

Is there a way to get IE11 to behave like IE9 did when debugging a web application with Visual Studio 2010?

When I hit F5, the browser will start and the application will display in the browser, but the Visual Studio JavaScript debugging is not attached to the browser.  I can manually attach the VS debugger to IE11, but that quickly turns into a hassle when your dealing with many iterations of start/stop/change/repeat.  Server side debugging is still working.

When I close the browser, Visual Studio 2010 does not stop the web application.  I have to manually click the Stop button.

I've tried many of the fixes suggested for using IE10 with Visual Studio 2010, but none of them have worked.

I have following installed:
Visual Studio 2010 with SP1
Visual Studio 2012 with Update 3.

**Update**
After uninstalling IE11 and reverting back to IE9 and that not working, I upgraded to IE10.  IE10 would not automatically attach to VS2010, but I could do it manually.  By some odd coincidence, my install of SR Ware Iron browser stopped working yesterday.  I uninstalled Iron and re-installed it.  Then I started using VS2010 and guess what?  IE10 was auto-hooked for debugging!  I can't explain it, but IE10 is working.

Answer (score 0):

You may have ran into the same problem I did, where IE11 would not allow Studio to attach a debugger because the Silverlight debugger must run in 32-bit mode.

IE11 (and IE10) typically run in 64-bit-only mode, but you can tweak them to enable 32-bit mode.  Read...

https://superuser.com/questions/561036/unable-to-open-ie-10-in-32-bit-mode

Or for more details about my experience with the Silverlight debugger, read...

[Visual Studio 2010 with IE 11 and 2.0 classic web pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197619/visual-studio-2010-with-ie-11-and-2-0-classic-web-pools)