# Visual Studio 2010 with IE 11 and 2.0 classic web pools

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i am using IIS in a visual studio 2010 solution with Integrated 4.0 and 2.0 Classic web pools.  when i use IE 11 over the Inet to "try" and login, the app fails.

yes i know about changing settings but this cannot happen on my web site.  Any thoughts on what is happening and / or why?

i have not tried to bring up the app using IE 11, any ideas on the "surprises" i will find?  thanks for any comments, they are appreciated.

Comment: I think you should restart the ISS, should use Integrated Pipeline   4.0  for 2010..Pool 2.0 classic meant for ASP.NET2.0

Comment: What does it mean "it fails"?

Comment: This is probably the wrong way to do something but its how this solution is "make" 1) i have a .net 4.0 solution 2) i have 2 projects that run IIS 2.0 Classic 3) I have 3 projects that are running IIS 4.0 integrated projects.

Comment: please let me know if this makes sense to run the solution this way or other IIS solution.  I have no idea why a solution "needs" multiple projects that have DEFAULT.ASPX pages, its a single signon app.

Comment: Just to make sure: are you saying that this works with IE 10 but not with IE 11? As others have asked, what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using VS2010.  I knew this problem existed with IE 10 and I somehow let the automatic updates install IE 11.

I found this fix from MS and it resolved the issue for me:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx

Comment: +1: What's up with the haters?  This answer was gold for me.  It didn't solve it all the way, but got me one step closer and thanks to it I was able to get IE 11 working with Studio's Silverlight debugger.  I realize it may not be answering the OP's exact question, but then again none of us are sure exactly what he's asking.  This answer does deserve credit for being a helpful towards solving IE11 + Studio 2010 integration issue.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies if this is wide of the OP's question, but I also had problems using Studio 2010 with the new IE 11 (googling those two terms led me here, and John B's post led me to answer).  Specifically Studio's debugger would fail to attach to IE 11 while I was launching a Silverlight project.

John B linked to an MSDN patch.  After I installed it, Studio still would fail to attach to IE11, but at least this time I got an error message: "The 32-bit version of the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot be used to debug 64-bit processes or 64-bit dumps. Please use the 64-bit version instead."

From that message I found out that Silverlight can only run in 32-bit mode.  And both IE10 and IE11 cannot run in 32-bit mode when they place all the tabs into a single 64-bit process.  However, if "Enhanced Protected Mode" is enabled (which it was for me by default, it's under Internet Options' Security tab) and you change this registry value...

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth

...to be something more than 0 (I set mine to 5, not sure it matters much as long as it's more than 0), then IE11 is able to spawn 32-bit processes and Studio is able to launch a 32-bit browser instance that it can attach the Silverlight debugger to.

A few related articles...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2716529

https://superuser.com/questions/561036/unable-to-open-ie-10-in-32-bit-mode

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774460/cannot-debug-silverlight-win7-x64-ie10

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I had an issue that was not the same as the OP. My problem was not being able to debug a Silverlight application. The debugger would start and then stop almost immediately, saying that the web hosting process exited. I followed the advice of John B and Gabe, and it fixed the issue. I am not sure which one fixed it. I wanted to mention that the registry key for me was under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE rather than HKEY_CURRENT_USER, as Gabe said.